# How does the size of the ginger affect the candy process?

Tags: food-preservation, candy, food-processing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-MFpM74SNw&ab_channel=Carolineartiss

I'm interested in candying ginger, like in this video. I want tiny candied ginger pieces to use in ginger biscuits. I'm just curious as to how if you grate ginger instead of just cutting pieces how that would or should affect the way you candy them?

I'm also feeling like leaving the skin on. I just don't feel like going through the effort of peeling the ginger. I don't know how good or bad an idea that is.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, it's easy to accidentally burn very small pieces. Candying grated ginger is probably possible, but would require excellent temperature control to prevent burned ginger. I like to candy mandolined slices (on one of the thicker settings) for minimal effort. As for peeling, there are a number of "hacks" for how to do it easily. I personally like using a teaspoon to scrape the peel off. (And I spend some time in the store picking a nice, smooth piece that will be easy to peel.) The peel is kind of unpleasantly papery and tough, even when cooked as thoroughly as candying requires.

Comment: Using a teaspoon is definitely the easiest.  Good idea on shopping for ginger that would be easy to peel.

Answer (score -1):

I'd "candy" the ginger in chunks (+/- US quarter coin sized) and chop them up when needed for other recipes.

And peel the ginger.